# Microsoft.VisualBasic.Financial.Rate errors with "Cannot calculate rate using the arguments provided"

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, exception, finance

So we have a rates calculator class in our ASP.NET4 web app that uses the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Financial.Rate to calculate a nominal rate (based on input parameters).

We noticed that for high values of NPer (total number of payment periods, e.g. 50 years x monthly payments = 600) the function would throw an exception: Cannot calculate rate using the arguments provided.

Searching around we did not find any solutions to this, so I am posting the solution here. A requirement for us was to maintain a function that as closely as possible implemented the same algorithm as the above, as we needed to produce exactly the same outputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question, for any future coders who run into this problem - we used dotPeek to decompile the module, which produced the following:

```
public static double Rate(double NPer, double Pmt, double PV, double FV = 0.0, DueDate Due = DueDate.EndOfPeriod, double Guess = 0.1)
{
  if (NPer <= 0.0)
    throw new ArgumentException(Utils.GetResourceString("Rate_NPerMustBeGTZero"));
  double Rate1 = Guess;
  double num1 = Financial.LEvalRate(Rate1, NPer, Pmt, PV, FV, Due);
  double Rate2 = num1 <= 0.0 ? Rate1 * 2.0 : Rate1 / 2.0;
  double num2 = Financial.LEvalRate(Rate2, NPer, Pmt, PV, FV, Due);
  int num3 = 0;
  do
  {
    if (num2 == num1)
    {
      if (Rate2 > Rate1)
        Rate1 -= 1E-05;
      else
        Rate1 -= -1E-05;
      num1 = Financial.LEvalRate(Rate1, NPer, Pmt, PV, FV, Due);
      if (num2 == num1)
        throw new ArgumentException(Utils.GetResourceString("Financial_CalcDivByZero"));
    }
    double Rate3 = Rate2 - (Rate2 - Rate1) * num2 / (num2 - num1);
    double num4 = Financial.LEvalRate(Rate3, NPer, Pmt, PV, FV, Due);
    if (Math.Abs(num4) < 1E-07)
      return Rate3;
    double num5 = num4;
    num1 = num2;
    num2 = num5;
    double num6 = Rate3;
    Rate1 = Rate2;
    Rate2 = num6;
    checked { ++num3; }
  }
  while (num3 <= 39);
  throw new ArgumentException(Utils.GetResourceString("Financial_CannotCalculateRate"));
}

private static double LEvalRate(double Rate, double NPer, double Pmt, double PV, double dFv, DueDate Due)
{
  if (Rate == 0.0)
    return PV + Pmt * NPer + dFv;
  double num1 = Math.Pow(Rate + 1.0, NPer);
  double num2 = Due == DueDate.EndOfPeriod ? 1.0 : 1.0 + Rate;
  return PV * num1 + Pmt * num2 * (num1 - 1.0) / Rate + dFv;
}
```

We can see the error is thrown if num3 is exceeded, as it has a hard limit at 39. We tidied up the code a little, and increased the limit to 100:

```
private static double CalculateUpfrontNominalRate(double numberOfPeriods, double payment, double presentValue, double futureValue = 0.0, DueDate Due = DueDate.EndOfPeriod, double Guess = 0.1)
    {
        if (numberOfPeriods <= 0.0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("CalculateUpfrontNominalRate: Number of periods must be greater than zero");
        }

        var rateUpperBoundary = Guess;
        var lEvalRate1 = LEvalRate(rateUpperBoundary, numberOfPeriods, payment, presentValue, futureValue, Due);
        var rateLowerBoundary = lEvalRate1 <= 0.0 ? rateUpperBoundary * 2.0 : rateUpperBoundary / 2.0;
        var lEvalRate2 = LEvalRate(rateLowerBoundary, numberOfPeriods, payment, presentValue, futureValue, Due);

        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (lEvalRate2 == lEvalRate1)
            {
                if (rateLowerBoundary > rateUpperBoundary)
                    rateUpperBoundary -= 1E-05;
                else
                    rateUpperBoundary -= -1E-05;

                lEvalRate1 = LEvalRate(rateUpperBoundary, numberOfPeriods, payment, presentValue, futureValue, Due);
                if (lEvalRate2 == lEvalRate1)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("CalculateUpfrontNominalRate: Inputs will cause a divsion by zero");
                }
            }

            double temporaryRate = rateLowerBoundary - (rateLowerBoundary - rateUpperBoundary) * lEvalRate2 / (lEvalRate2 - lEvalRate1);
            double lEvalRate3 = LEvalRate(temporaryRate, numberOfPeriods, payment, presentValue, futureValue, Due);

            if (Math.Abs(lEvalRate3) < 1E-07)
            {
                return temporaryRate;
            }

            lEvalRate1 = lEvalRate2;
            lEvalRate2 = lEvalRate3;
            rateUpperBoundary = rateLowerBoundary;
            rateLowerBoundary = temporaryRate;
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("CalculateUpfrontNominalRate: The maximum number of iterations has been exceeded, unable to calculate rate");
    }

    private static double LEvalRate(double Rate, double NPer, double Pmt, double PV, double dFv, DueDate Due)
    {
        if (Rate == 0.0)
            return PV + Pmt * NPer + dFv;
        double num1 = Math.Pow(Rate + 1.0, NPer);
        double num2 = Due == DueDate.EndOfPeriod ? 1.0 : 1.0 + Rate;
        return PV * num1 + Pmt * num2 * (num1 - 1.0) / Rate + dFv;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the count of iterative calculations won't solve the problem for all cases

For the sample calculation your posted, the rate algorithm did not find the rate within 40 iterations that was correct to 7 decimal places (accurate to 7 decimal places)

Is this the programming code from Vb.net financial functions that you have decompiled

If so, the programmer has done a poor job of coding the RATE function with Secant method

There are far better algorithms to use to find interest rates than the lousy Secant method

If you think you have solved the problem by changing the iterations to 100 then try to test the code with various data and see if you can get the RATE in all instances

Comment: Thanks Abraham, interesting to know - yes, that is a directly decompiled, and it struck me as well that it was badly done. 
With regards to the "fix" I've run a number of simulations on the data ranges our product can produce, and the new limit does seem to cover our cases. We are configging out the number of iterations (which seems like a poor workaround), but it sounds like you have better knowledge then I on this area. Do you have a better recommendation of an algorithm that we should use?

Comment: As you noticed yourself, the Secant method performs poorly when it comes to convergence of a root of a 600 degree polynomial. If you seek an algorithm that converges faster then you may want to try out the Newton Raphson or the Modified Newton Raphson method. For the former you will need to find one derivative and for the latter you would have to find the derivative of a derivative (a second order derivative). But even these two methods will only find one or zero roots so you may not even find the rate with the default seed value of 10%

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems using the Rate function. 
Found out that your 'guess' is very important to ensure convergence - as outlined in the [Remarks in the documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/rate-function-9f665657-4a7e-4bb7-a030-83fc59e748ce):

> **Remarks**:
>
> Make sure that you are consistent about the units you use for
>   specifying guess and nper. If you make monthly payments on a four-year
>   loan at 12 percent annual interest, use 12%/12 for guess and 4*12 for
>   nper. If you make annual payments on the same loan, use 12% for guess
>   and 4 for nper.

Answer (score 0):

If you're italian and going insane while trying to use Excel's *Rata* function from C# or VB.NET, beware of the fact that the Rata function [is called Pmt in english](https://www.corsi-excel-roma.it/blog-articoli/excel-funzioni.html). The Rate function is something entirely different.

```
Financial.Pmt(tassoTemp / 12, durataMutuo * 12, -importoMutuo);
```